# Paris & a cruise?

Tags: paris, cruising

I want to take my 18 year old grandson on a graduation trip to Paris in June. We would also like to take a cruise. We only have 2 weeks. Any suggestions on ports, itineraries, and best use of time and money. Will we need visas?

Comment: River or ocean cruise?

Comment: Visa depwnds on your nationality and on the destinations.

Comment: Please have a read of the [help] - asking for suggestions is under the 'we are not travel agents' clause - each person's itinerary or dream trip is different, and this site is for objective q&as, not like a regular forum :/